# AWS S3 Bucket: What is TagStorage-TagHrs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Our AWS S3 bucket has 10,000 images, and each image had 5 tags, so in total, we had 50,000 tags and we were getting charged for that.

From the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-dg.pdf), it says that:

```
region-TagStorage-TagHrs: The total of tags on all objects in the bucket reported by hour
```

Now, we want to cut the costs, and hence we deleted all 5 tags across each image, but still, we see that charges are getting applied. Does anyone know how to understand these charges?

[image]

Comment: The previous tag hour still counts, but the usage won't increment any more if you delete all tags.

Comment: But usage got restarted on 1-June-2020, we still see that it is getting increased.

Answer (score 0):

The billing suggests that there are more objects with tags.

I couldn't find a way to easily list all objects with tags, so here's a Python script that will iterate through all buckets and objects in a region:

```py
import boto3

REGION = 'ap-southeast-2'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', region_name = REGION)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = REGION)

for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
    for object in bucket.objects.all():
        response = s3_client.get_object_tagging(Bucket = bucket.name, Key = object.key)
        for tag in response['TagSet']:
            print('Tag found: ', tag['Key'], tag['Value'])s3
```